# Warn customers of incorrect runtime version on Application Pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We are moving our ASP.NET product from the .NET Framework 3.5 to 4.5.1 as a part of this, our customers will need to change their application pool from CLR version 2.0 to 4.0.

The vast majority of our customers install with an MSI that correctly configures the application pool. Occasionally, we have customers that manually setup their application pools for the application. We want to be able to tell them, "Hey, you have the wrong CLR version selected in the application pool" using the product itself.

We achieved something similar for the pipeline mode. We did this by making an HttpModule that has a precondition of `integratedMode`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
  <add preCondition="integratedMode" name="IisPipelineCheckModule" type="IisPiplineCheckModule, OurAssembly, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba36f1f458df13fd" />
  </modules>
```

All this HTTP module does is spit out an HTML page instructing them to change their AppPool to classic pipeline (which we require):

```cs
application.Response.ClearContent();
application.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
application.Response.WriteFile(application.Server.MapPath("~/pipeline.htm"));
application.Response.End();
```

We attempted to do something similar by adding a runtime version precondition for 2.0 to instruct customers to change the runtime version to 4.0:

```xml
<add preCondition="runtimeVersionv2.0" name="IisNetFxCheckModule" type="NetFxVersionCheckModule, SomeAssemblyCompiledFor20Clr, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba36f1f458df13fd" />
```

Unfortunately, this has several problems. If the AppPool is set to CLR 2.0 incorrectly, it can't even get past parsing the web.config since it may contain elements and attributes that are new to 4.0, such as `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`. This will blow up before it even gets close to executing the HttpModule. Likewise, if the "bin" contains assemblies compiled for the 4.0 CLR, there will be assembly loading exceptions indicating the assembly was built for a newer version of the runtime.

I think what I am looking for is flat-out impossible, there is no way for us to hook early enough in the application's lifetime to warn about the incorrect CLR version, before the bin is even probed for assemblies, or the web.config is parsed.

Is there something I have overlooked where this might be possible? We can assume the IIS version is 7.0 or greater.

Comment: +1 Now *that's* a question! _Learned_ something already just by reading the _question_ -  Woot!

Comment: Does it really have to be that early in the lifecycle? Can you check `System.Environment.Version` somewhere at the entry point (e.g. Page_Init of Default.aspx)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It needs to be *early*, before the ASP.NET framework is even loaded. `Page_Init` won't work because IIS can't even get past the point of loading the web.config. Even if it *could* get past the web.config (say we managed to make it 2.0 compatible, somehow) the ASP.NET build manager will bomb on `CompileGlobalAsax` because there will be assemblies in the bin compiled for 4.0, which won't load.

Comment: I don't see the point.  This is a one-time event.  Once the app pool is configured, it will never need to be configured again.  So why force the running of a module every time a request comes in, just to check for something that happens once during the installation of the app?

Comment: @ErikTheViking because customers will configure it incorrectly, then just assume "oh, the product is broken" as opposed to us showing a useful error message. The module will not run for every request when preconditions are applied.

Answer (score 0):

One option, you could have a "default" web.config that only runs your module, and it's configured for version 2.0 clr.  It checks the app pool, and if everything is ok, it copies the "real" web.config over the default one.

If it's not, it displays the error message until the app pool is configured correctly.